# segmented control color not showing when going back and fourth from view

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, viewdidload

my segmented control shows the purple text that I want when first being loaded, however when I press back on the navigation bar and then back into the view the color is gone. I have tried it in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {

    mySegmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
    mySegmentedControl.setFontSize(fontSize: 14)

    UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.purple], for: UIControlState.selected)

    super.viewDidLoad()


}
```

Comment: Hi,can u try by setting selectedSegmentIndex property of UISegmentContro l in view will appear.Generally,Segment control behaviour is selected segment text color will be in background color of segment control and remaining tabs in segment control filled with tintcolor.

Comment: @shanmugamsekar again won't show purple after second time showing view

Comment: can u share your code snippet if you want .may be able to help you.shanippt@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set `setTitleTextAttributes` for each `UISegmentedControl` instead of setting for all `UISegmentedControl`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mySegmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
    mySegmentedControl.setFontSize(fontSize: 14)
    mySegmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.purple], for: .selected)
}
```